# Sybase - SQL Linked server: The parameter is incorrect when using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-ase

I have been using an SQL Server that has a Sybase server set up as a linked server.

I can query the linked server's tables by this

```
SELECT * FROM [LinkDb].[Database].[dbo].TABLENAME
```

Today I encountered an issue, when I was trying to use variables to filter date from and to values.

I narrowed it down to this **query**:

```
declare @dateVal nvarchar(90)
set @dateVal = (select convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) + '0000')

select * from [LinkDb].[Database].[dbo].TABLENAME
where datevalue >= '2014-10-06T00:00:00.0000000' 
and datevalue <= @dateVal
```

Which returns the **error message**:

`OLE DB provider "Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider" for linked server "SSE" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.`
".

Not sure on what should be ticked here, but these are the Provider Parameters for my Sybase Connection.

[image: Server Provider Settings]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to query with some other column in the where clause?

Comment: @nikadim if the values are literate then yes, but if I try using a variable as a value, it throws the error above

Comment: Will this work: 
select * from [LinkDb].[Database].[dbo].TABLENAME
where datevalue >= '2014-10-06T00:00:00.0000000'. You are providing 7 digits for milliseconds. Format is defined with six: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS:SSSSSS. Is this an issue?

Comment: @nikadim - Got back in the office, I can test now. Both 6 and 7 digits work when using literal values. Variable still not working no matter what format am I trying to use with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get around this, by using a nested query.

May work for anyone experiencing the same.

```
select * from [LinkDb].[Database].[dbo].TABLENAME
where datevalue >= '2014-10-06T00:00:00.0000000' 
and datevalue <= (SELECT MAX(datevalue) FROM [LinkDb].[Database].[dbo].TABLENAME)
```